# Playback in Kinect Studio without a sensor connected

Tags: wpf, kinect

I would like to know if anyone has managed to playback recordings from the Kinect Studio (.XED files) when the Kinect Sensor is **not** connected to the computer, or if it's possible? The playback works as expected when the sensor is connected.

A quick Google search did not yield many results, and all I can find in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131036.aspx) is that:

"Kinect Studio must be used in conjunction with a Kinect for Windows application".

For those wondering why: I am going away for a week where it is not feasible to take the sensor with me, but I wish to continue development - I was hoping I could make a set of recordings to see me through the week...

Comment: Also as mentioned under Known Issues @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131036.aspx

In v1.5.0 and v1.5.1, Kinect Studio recordings (stored in .xed files) play properly only when the same Kinect sensor is being used by the application. You should keep a record of the precise sensor used to record each file so that you can play the file back with correct synchronization between color and depth cameras. With future updates, we plan to update the information that Kinect Studio stores in the .xed file so that playback is possible using any sensor.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that. Hopefully they will support this functionality in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855396.aspx
It says,

There are four states the KinectStudio tool can be in:

Disconnected, no open file - idle
Disconnected, file open - play the file in Kinect Studio
Connected, no open file - mirror the Kinect-enabled application sensor output in Kinect Studio and record it
Connected, file open - can play back the file into the Kinect-enabled application.

I did manage to playback my recorded data (.xed file) via the kinect studio without the kinect sensor.

Comment: If you could have just also told us how you managed.. It would have really helpfull..

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game but I think I found a solution.

Go to Device Manager -> Action -> Add Legacy hardware -> Manually select Kinect device and install.

Restart Kinect Studio and you will be able to connect to service and playback without physically connecting to a Kinect.